# Android java: getter methods is giving null values

Tags: java, android, getter-setter, pojo

Hi in my app i am using a model class with setter and getter methods, in one of my fragnment iam setting the lat lng values and i wanna get those values in another Activity, but it is  giving null values:

My model class:

```
public class LatLngModel {

    double Latitude;
    double Longitude;

    public LatLngModel(double latitude, double longtitude) {
        this.Latitude = latitude;
        this.Longitude = longtitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }
    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
    }
    public double getLongitude() {
        return this.Longitude;
    }
    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        Longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

I am setting the values as below in classA which extends fragment

```
LatLngModel model = new LatLngModel(latitude,longtitude);
    model.setLatitude(latitude);
    model.setLongitude(longtitude);
```

Below is how iam acessing the get methods in classB extends Activity

```
LatLngModel model = new LatLngModel(latitude,longtitude);

        System.out.println("getting lat" +(model.getLatitude())) ;
        System.out.println("getting lat" +(model.getLongitude())) ;
```

But its is printing null values, Any help is appreciated

Comment: Maybe the values being passed to the LatLngModel constructor are null?

Comment: The problem should be somewhere else, a `double` variable cannot be `null`.

Comment: You should pass the instance of `LatLngModel` you created in `classA`. In `classB` you now create a new instance which is unrelated to the one on which you set those values.

Comment: I think when you are getting values using `getters` you are using new `LatLngModel object`.. Are you using the same `object` to get the values ?

Comment: are you sure that in `new LatLngModel(latitude,longtitude)` both parameters are not `null` or valid `double`?

Comment: It is **impossible** for the code you've posted to print `null` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the values using different objects

```
LatLngModel model = new LatLngModel(latitude,longtitude);
model.setLatitude(latitude);
model.setLongitude(longtitude);
```

Consider the above as `Object A`

LatLngModel model = `new` LatLngModel(latitude,longtitude);

Before acessing , you should make sure that you are using the same object, Using `new` will create another object

**UPDATE**

Simplest but singleton solution

```
private LatLngModel instance;

public static LatLngModel GetInstance()
{
if(instance == null)
    instance = new LatLngModel();
return instance;
}
```

Then call

`LatLngModel.getInstance();`

to get the same object from any class .

**NOTE**

Dont call new for this class

Comment: If you're going to suggest a singleton (which you shouldn't), at least do it the right way; the preferred way to create a singleton in Java is using an `enum`

Comment: If you know that way , Just tell him how, Iam not a master This is how i do.If you know better way i will follow

Comment: @Arju hey thanks it worked and i search online i see many people are using this type of singleton. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BrianRoach Can u let us know you approach..Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new model in your classB and so the data is gone. You need to pass the model you made in classA to classB so you can re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

You must define your class/variable as static before you can reference between any two different classes/activities.

Try to define them as static and you must be able to access the same.

Comment: Encouraging the use of static variables like this is not helping anyone.

Comment: I agree with Brian on "Avoid Static unless really required" the static solution will just work in your case but then use them wisely. Alternative can be persist the data in a store and access them by passing as a parameter between the activities. @BrianRoach let me know your thought

Comment: Honestly it's unclear what the OP's actual issue is. It is impossible for the code they have posted to output `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

```
LatLngModel model = new LatLngModel(latitude,longtitude);
```

will create a new object. So the values will be null in new object. Pass lat long using intent.

That will not give null.

Example:

FirstActivity:

```
//Send data to second activity

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainTabActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("lat", model.getLatitude());
intent.putExtra("long", model.getLongitude());
startActivity(secondActivity);
```

SecondActivity:

```
//Get data from intent
double latitude;
double longitude;
Intent intent = getIntent();
latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat",'0.0'); //0.0 is default value
longitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("long",'0.0'); //0.0 is default value
```

Comment: Hi..can u brief your answer with sample code..Thankyou

Comment: @teekib I added a little example.